# Unknown property when using html-data-id attribute in apex:dataTable

Tags: apex, visualforce, compile-error

I am getting a unknown property error, when using the `var` from data table in a html-data-id attribute, it is working in apex attributes perfect. I can't figure out how to make it work for `html-data-id` attribute.

```
                <apex:dataTable value="{!flatProductlineItems}" var="lineItem">
                    <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Opportunity_Line_Item__c.fields.Category__c.Label}" styleClass="{!if(lineItem.showError=true,'ErrorInRed','')}">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!lineItem.product.Category__c}" rendered="{!IF(lineItem.lastRecord, false, true)}" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Opportunity_Line_Item__c.fields.District__c.Label}" styleClass="{!if(lineItem.showError=true,'ErrorInRed','')}">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!lineItem.product.District__c}" rendered="{!IF(lineItem.lastRecord, false, true)}" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Opportunity_Line_Item__c.fields.Start_Date__c.Label}" styleClass="{!if(lineItem.showError=true,'ErrorInRed','')}">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!lineItem.product.Start_Date__c}" rendered="{!IF(lineItem.lastRecord == false, true, false)}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Opportunity_Line_Item__c.fields.Total_Amount__c.label}" styleClass="{!if(lineItem.showError=true,'ErrorInRed','')}">
                        <apex:inputText html-data-id="{!lineItem.position}" style="text-align:right;" value="{!lineItem.product.Total_Amount__c}" rendered="{!IF(lineItem.lastRecord == false, true, false)}" />
                        <apex:inputText value="{!lineItem.subTotalAmount}" style="text-align:right;" rendered="{!lineItem.lastRecord}" html-readonly="true" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column styleClass="{!if(lineItem.showError=true,'ErrorInRed','')}">.
                        <apex:commandButton value="-" action="{!removeFlatProduct}" status="LoadingSpinner" rendered="{!IF(lineItem.lastRecord == false, true, false)}" reRender="flatPanelContainer,errorPanel" style="text-align:center;width:20px;">
                            <apex:param name="flatProductToRemove" value="{!lineItem.position}" assignTo="{!flatProductToRemove}" />
                        </apex:commandButton>
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:dataTable>
```

I am getting an error that the property `lineItem` is not found in the controller  , however it should use the property from `var` attribute.
Here is the flatProductLineItems variable in the controller:

```
   public List<LineItemWrapper> flatProductLineItems { get {
        if(flatProductLineItems == null) {
            flatProductLineItems = new List<LineItemWrapper>();
        }
        return flatProductLineItems;
    } set; }
```

If i remove the attribute `html-data-id` from the `apex:inputText` everything is compiling and working ok.

Comment: Can you please post the flatProductlineItems's class as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I tried and it's working for me. Make sure you put the datatable tags inside the apex:form tag.

```
    <apex:page controller="CONTROLLER">
     <apex:form>
      <apex:dataTable value="{!LIST}" var="VAR">
        <apex:column headerValue="Name">
            <apex:inputText html-data-id="{!VAR.NameString}" value=" 
                                                            {!VAR.NameString}"/>
        </apex:column>
     </apex:dataTable>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```